# PHP $_GET Method ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

```
<a href="?sayfa=oyun_listesi&siralama=isim-az">A-Z</a>
<a href="?sayfa=oyun_listesi&siralama=isim-za">Z-A</a>

<?php
echo $_GET['siralama'];
if(empty($_GET['siralama'])){
$oyunlar = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM oyunlar");
}
else if(isset($_GET['siralama'])){
if($_GET['siralama']='isim-az'){$oyunlar = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM oyunlar ORDER BY oyun_isim");}
else if($_GET['siralama']='isim-za'){$oyunlar = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM oyunlar ORDER BY oyun_isim DESC");}
}
while($oyun = mysqli_fetch_array($oyunlar))
{
?>
SQL Variables + HTML
<?php } mysqli_close($con);?>
```

i have two link with $_GET variable i can echo $_GET['siralama'] but it wont change $oyunlar variable it should ORDER BY DESC while isim_za but it wont.

Comment: Formatting your code will help alot

Comment: With `$x = $y`, you're assigning the value of `$y` to `$x`. For comparing `$x` and `$y`, do `if ( $x == $y )` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if($_GET['siralama']='isim-az')
```

to

```
if($_GET['siralama']=='isim-az')
```

-- edit

Answer (score 0):

You are using one = which is setting the variable.  For comparisons, be sure to use ==.

```
if($_GET['siralama']=='isim-az'){
```